# how change style value of previous element

Tags: html, css, angular

i have elements and when click down with the mouse the color of text changing from black to red

my problem is that i want when i click an another element so this elemnt changing to red and the previous element return to be black

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelect]'
})

export class SelectDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown') onmousedown() {
    if (this.elRef.nativeElement.style.color !== 'red') {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'red');

    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'black');
    }
```

Comment: So what is the issue? What happens? Best would be that you create a stackblitz showcasing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a directive to change style is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. But you can do adding a Output to your directive.

In general -without directive- we can do some like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index" 
    [style.color]="selectedIndex==i?'red':'black'" 
    (click)="selectedIndex=i" >
    click me
</div>
```

when we has defined a variable like

```
  selectedIndex:number=-1;
```

If you want use a directive we can do some similar. We defined a variable like

```
  control:any={}
```

And we write some like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4]"
     [appSelect]="control" 
     (onSelect)="control=$event" >
    click me
</div>
```

Where our directive is

```
export class SelectDirective implements AfterViewChecked {

  @Input('appSelect') control;
  @Output() onSelect:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.elRef.nativeElement==this.control)
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'red');
    else 
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'black');
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown') onmousedown() {
    this.onSelect.emit(this.elRef.nativeElement);

  }
}
```

See that we change the color in the event AfterViewChecked. You can see the result of both solutions in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1t3nu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)